# Evaluating/combining PDFs over time to predict future value

Tags: predictive-models, density-function

I am trying to predict a value over time. I have historical data that I have used to calculate PDFs for the change over various time intervals.

If I'm trying to predict the value at time T0 and start at T-10. I measure the current actual value, multiply it by the T-10 PDF and get prediction distribution.

Time passes and now I'm at T-9, and I want to make another prediction. I could just do the same thing again, measure actual and multiply by the T-9 PDF and use that. My question is, is there a predictive advantage of using the previous PDFs and actual values as well and how would one do that?

For example, if it's currently T-5, I could take the actual values for now and the previous 4 times, multiply them by the respective T-[10 through 5] PDFs and somehow combine them.

Is there value in doing that and if so, what is the appropriate calculation to do so?

(Note: I'm actually not using discrete times, but rather can interpolate the PDF from continuous time intervals. However, I assumed the discrete case would be simpler to discuss so formed the question in that way)

Comment: "is there a predictive advantage of using the previous PDFs and actual values" -- there's no information in your post with which to answer such a question either way. It's perfectly possible that the answer is either 'yes' or 'no', depending on what these "T-$n$" distributions consist of and what sort of process it is. It's also not clear why one would "*measure the current actual value, multiply it by the T-10 PDF*" in order to "*get prediction distribution*". Typically multiplying a distribution by a constant doesn't yield a distribution.

Comment: I apologize I don't know terminology well. It's not multiplying by a "constant". The x-axis of the PDF represents the probability of the change over a time interval. Multiply change by the current value and you get the predicted value. So, by "multiplying" by a current value of say 5.3, it converts the PDF from "the probability that the value will increase by x% (eg. 15%)" to "the probability the value will be 5.3*(1+x%) (eg. 6.095)".

Comment: Ah, you're multiplying the current value by a random variable which has some particular pdf.

Answer (score 0):

This question could be just closed because it's a little unclear as the first comment indicates. However, it might be useful to have an answer that might suggest some direction.

I think the answer is that it depends on the particular case. It seems likely that if one is concerned about including the previous states in the prediction, than one should choose a different overall model (maybe google time series forecasting/prediction) to begin with that includes it. Trying to tack it on after the fact probably is not an ideal approach.